# Why can access the variable in "what-I-think-is-a-closure"?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have code like this: (and on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k6zNm/3/)

```
(function(){
    Marker = function(opts){
        var marker = this;
        marker.Version = "2012.Jul.06";
        marker.HelloWorld = function(){
            return marker.Version;
        }
    }
})();

window.mymarker = new Marker();
$("div#message").text(mymarker.HelloWorld());
```

The code works fine. But I think the `(function(){})();` is a closure. Why can I access the `Marker` in it. Isn't it a pollution to global namespace?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a "closure" (where a function wraps around a variable) with "clojure" (a programming language).

Comment: the typing method changed it for me. thanks for help :)

Comment: If you think about a closure having access to all variables in the higher scope, then yes, it is a closure, because all functions have that characteristic. But strictly speaking, a function is only a closure if it is accessible even after the context it was created in (e.g. an other function) terminated. From that perspective, this is not a closure since you are defining the function and execute it immediately. This "pattern" has little to do with closures, it's about creating scope by executing a function.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm beginning learning about js and closures. To speak of this example, can I imagine that adding code that is really a closure inside this `pattern`, right?

Comment: A closure is a function + a reference to an enclosing environment. A function on its own isn't a closure. And functions that don't reference an enclosing environment need not be implemented as closures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't used [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) with `Marker`, so it is a global variable instead of being scoped to the function.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. So without `var`, the `Marker` was attached to `window`? `window.Marker`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a closure. A closure is like below, you need to return the function out, note that the variable `version` is out of your returned function scope.

```
var Marker = (function(){
    var version = "2012.Jul.06";
    return function(opts){
        var marker = this;
        marker.Version = version;
        marker.HelloWorld = function(){
            return marker.Version;
        };
    };
})();
```

You could access `Marker` is just because it is a global variable in your code.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Isn't it? Could you explain more?

Comment: It's a closure. Clojure is a programming language.

Comment: @xdazz It's spelled "closure" with an S. Since this is the only correct answer, I won't downvote, but neither can I upvote.

Comment: Every function is a closure in lexical scope eg with respect to parent scope: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/

Comment: This wrong. A closure **does not require `return`**. Imagine the case of using an invoked-immediately function passed out of the current lexical scope. (It does however, correctly point out that `Marker` is a window property.)

Comment: @pst Could you make an example?

Comment: `(function (g) { var x = 0; g(function (qv) { x = qv }); return x })(function (q) { q(42) })`, which results in 42. The variable `x` was closed-over by the anonymous function (that "created a closure") passed to (and then invoked by) the function known as `g`. The `return` is purely to return the *result*, and is not related to the function-objects.

Comment: @pst Thank you very much. But in this case, closure despairs soon as the anonymous function executed. If you don't use return, you could not access the closure scope any more.

Comment: @xdazz My issue is with the *wording* used. It *is* a closure. However, as noted, it is the window property which is assigned to: this doesn't make it "not a closure", but rather allows the behavior observed. Furthermore, the code in this answer has the *same semantics* - it just goes about getting them a slightly different way. (In both cases the *same closure'd function* is assigned to a window property.)

Comment: @pst So could you plz edit my answer to correct the wrong part :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't put `var` in front of Marker, thats why it get created in global level.

Answer (score 0):

The closure is just the upper scope. For example:

```
( function() {
    var i = 0;
    ( function() {
        // i is in the closure, the upper scope
    } () );
} () );
```

Don't forget that javascript's only scope is function scope.

`(function(){})();` is an immediately invoked function expression.

But yeah, for your example, the problem is just that you missed the `var`, so `Marker` is a global variable.

Comment: He's also missing `return`, as is your example, but you also call the enclosed function which is just nonsense.

Comment: @Potatoswatter the example is just there to show the principle of a closure, it's not a working example.